# How to create (number) series with custom intervals in LibreOffice

Tags: time-series, libreoffice-calc

Imagine you have the following table, see down below. Now, I would like to tell LibreOffice to create out of all three columns a series with custom intervals each. Is this possible?

The series shall be like this:

1. Increase number by 1 every 112 rows and insert current number inbetween.
2. Increase number by 1 every 28 rows and insert current number inbetween.
3. Increase number by 1 every 7 rows and insert current number inbetween.

[image]

Comment: Just incrementing every certain number of rows can be done by `=INT((ROW()-1)/112) +1` where you'd replace 112 by whatever your interval is.  I'm not understanding what you mean by "insert current number inbetween", though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use formula `=INT((ROW()-1)/period)+startingNumber` and drag it down (with black square at the bottom right of selected cell) to copy it to number of rows.

Or you can use simple macro (where `period` equals 7, 28 or 112):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main

    Dim numberOfRows, n, period, startingNumber As Integer
    Dim destinationCell As Variant

    period = 7
    numberOfRows = 30
    startingNumber = 1
    For n = 0 To numberOfRows-1
        destinationCell=ThisComponent.Sheets.getByIndex(0).getCellByPosition(0,n)
        destinationCell.setValue(Int(n/period)+startingNumber)
    Next n

End Sub
```